# TemplateView in Django with custom status code

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have internal account privacy permissions in my project(e.g. only friends can see profile page of user) and I want to have custom permission denied page for this case. Is there any way to return response from TemplateView with status code equals 403?

Something like this:

```
class PrivacyDeniedView(TempateView):
    template_name = '...'
    status_code = 403
```

I can do this by override dispatch() but maybe Django has out of the box solution

Answer: it looks like there no generic solution. The best way is proposed by @alecxe, but encapsulated in Mixin as @FoxMaSk proposed

Comment: Check out the answer I just posted which is quite similar to the hypothetical snippet you included above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option is to override [get()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L153) method of your `TemplateView` class:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return self.render_to_response(context, status=403)
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this solution, but as for me it looks a little ugly(

Comment: If i'm not worng @MaxKharandziuk in fact no it's not urgly as `TemplateView` inherits from `BaseView` which provides it.

Comment: I mean I will be prefer to change status code as I mentioned in question:)

Comment: may be you can then do a Mixin and use it in your `class foobar(TemplateView, FoobarMixin)` ?

Answer (score 6):

You can subclass `TemplateResponse` and set `response_class` in the view.  For example:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

class TemplateResponseForbidden(TemplateResponse):
    status_code = 403

class PrivacyDeniedView(TemplateView):
    response_class = TemplateResponseForbidden
    ...
```

This approach is more DRY than the other suggestions because you don't need to copy and paste any code from `TemplateView` (e.g. the call to `render_to_string()`).

I tested this in Django 1.6.

Comment: Nice idea. What would be the best method to put this into? If I want to make it conditional and not render 403 all the time.

Answer (score 3):

While alecxe's answer works, I strongly suggest you to avoid overriding `get`; it's easy to forget that CBV's can have other methods like `post`, and if you're overriding one you should do the same for the others.

In fact, there is no need to create a separate view just to display a 403 error; Django already has `django.http.HttpResponseForbidden`. So instead of redirecting to your view, just do something along the lines of:

```
if not user.has_permission(): # or however you check the permission
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Or, if you want to render a particular template:

```
if not user.has_permission(): # or however you check the permission
    return HttpResponseForbidden(loader.render_to_string("403.html"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this problem as well. My goal was to be able to specify the status code in urls.py, e.g.:

```
url(r'^login/error/?$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='auth/login_error.html', status=503), name='login_error'),
```

So using the previous answers in this thread as idea starters, I came up with the following solution:

```
class TemplateView(django.views.generic.TemplateView):

    status = 200

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):

        response_kwargs['status'] = self.status

        return super(TemplateView, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I came across it first when searching. I was using a different generic view (`ListView`) whose implementation for `get` is a bit more complex, and thus a bit of a mess to override. I went for this solution instead:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(ListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    response.status_code = 403
    return response
```

This also allowed me to decide the status code based on some parameters of the request, which was necessary in my case to perform a 301 redirect for old-style URL patterns.

If you don't require the ability to change status code from within the method, then [cjerdonek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21323657/3768332) is ideal.